# My wordpress admin backend doesnt go to links anymore

Tags: wp-admin

Before I even updated the site, I realized something was wrong, all the CSS was missing at wp-admin. I tried updating the wordpress corefiles with fresh installation, I tried flushing permalinks, I removed .htaccess. Also updated my theme and the database version but whenever I go to anything beyond wp-admin/option or pages or post,whichever, it says 404. Also removed plugin folder and went back to a default theme. However the front end works and all the other plugin section tend to work, seem to just be the dashboard admin section itself. What else should I try?